# Who introduced moments of a random variable first?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, math-history

When, by whom and in which paper where moments of a random variable used first in probability theory?

Question moved to : https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/who-introduced-moments-of-a-random-variable-first

Comment: I agree "too broad" is not a good close reason.  Maybe "not research mathematics" is OK as a close reason.  On the other hand, citing a non-closed post from 5 years ago does not show what today's standards for closing are.

Comment: This feels like good scholarship to me

Comment: Personally, I did not vote to close.  But in fact this question fits better at "History of Science and Mathematics" https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: This sites deals with mathematical problems, and more specifically reasoning steps where the asker is stuck. Little to do with the history of Mathematics, hence off-topic. I just voted to close the question you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MathWords](http://jeff560.tripod.com/m.html)

> **Moment** was taken into Statistics from Mechanics by Karl Pearson when he treated the frequency-curve (or observation curve) as the sheet enclosed by the curve and the horizontal axis. See his "Asymmetrical Frequency Curves," *Nature* October 26th 1893: "Now the centre of gravity of the observation curve is found at once, also its area and its first four moments by easy calculation." [OED].

> The phrase **method of moments** was used in a statistics sense in the first of Karl Pearson’s "Contributions to the Mathematical Theory of Evolution," (*Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society* A, 185, (1894), p. 75.). Pearson used the method to estimate the parameters of a mixture of normal distributions. For several years Pearson used the method on different problems but the name only gained general currency with the publication of his 1902 *Biometrika* paper "On the systematic fitting of curves to observations and measurements" (David 1995). In "On the Mathematical Foundations of Theoretical Statistics" (*Phil. Trans. R. Soc.* 1922), Fisher criticized the method for being inefficient compared to his own maximum likelihood method (Hald pp. 650 and 719).

> **Moment generating function**. R. A. Fisher seems to have brought this term into English in his "Moments and Product Moments of Sampling Distributions.," *Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society*, Series 2, 30, (1929), p. 238. He probably took the term from V. Romanovsky "Sur Certaines Éspérances Mathématiques et sur l'Erreur Moyenenne du Coefficient de Corrélation, *Comptes Rendus*, 180, (1925), 1897-1899. Romanovsky refers to "la function génératrice des moments" (p. 1898).